# How to solve this NDSolve problem in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

I found a confused problem in solving a ODE problems with NDSolve in Mathematica, the code is as follows:

I have tried 'Clear[Derivative]' and restart the kernel but these methods don't work.

Here is the question:

[image: origial question]

Here is my Mathematica code:

```
Clear[Derivative];

ClearSystemCache;

r = 0.3; a = 3; delta = 0.45; M0 = 0.975; T = 20;
u[t] = 0.5*l[t]*delta*M[t];
eql1 = M'[t] == r*M[t] Log[1/M[t]] - u[t]*delta*M[t];

eql2 = l'[t] == -2 *a *M[t] - l[t]* r *Log[1/M[t]] + l[t]*r - 
    l[t]*u[t]*delta;

condition = {M[0] == M0, l[T] == 0};

sol = NDSolve[Flatten@{{eql1, eql2}, condition}, {M, l}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

However this has problems, here is the problem result

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. \[Infinity] encountered.

Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. \[Infinity] encountered.

Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

General::stop: Further output of Power::infy will be suppressed during this calculation.

Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.

General::stop: Further output of Infinity::indet will be suppressed during this calculation.

NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.
```

The result picture is here

[image: result of code]

I can't figure out why there be "non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0", there shouldn't be non-numerical value at t==0, the whole M[t] should be >0 when t<=20. I have spent a lot of time on this problem and still could not find an answer, please help me.

Best regards!

Comment: Cross-posting - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023820/how-to-solve-this-ndsolve-problem-in-mathematica - is rather frowned upon in the Stackiverse, leading to fragmentation, confusion and who-knows what else.  Choose a site to ask your question at, delete it at any others.

Comment: You've got a boundary value problem.  To see what's going on, convert it to an initial value problem by using `condition  = {l[0] == l0, M[0] == M0}`and try to guess `l0`.  I find that `l0` needs to be at least 10^89 to avoid a singularity for `0 < t < 20`.  In that case `l[20] = -57.6858`. Increasing `l0` to 10^154 and still `l[20] = -1.30193`, not reaching your desired boundary value of 0.  Unfortunately beyond that, again `NDSolve` fails.  But these crazy large numbers make me think there's something wrong with your equations or parameter values.